# How to expand a cell view to another view controller's view? Just like secret app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-animation

I think the ios secret app is very cool and want to implement its animation. But I don't know how to make it. That is when a cell in time line clicked by user, the cell expends to whole screen, but the other cells don't move. It seems that the cell becomes another view controller's view. When the user click the close button on the top left side, it scale small to it was before. Just like the photos show:

[image]
[image]

I thought its something ios7 view controller transition trick, but I didn't make it. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I posted one way to do it here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23039129/ios-animate-table-view-cell-into-full-screen-when-tapped/23039835#23039835. That method does actually present the view of another view controller.

Comment: @rdelmar Thank you very much. But I wanna implement it just like Photos app & Calenda app in IOS7 which using the ios7 new transition api. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I think the Photos app is using code similar to what's in the CollectionViewTransition project which is available from the iOS Dev center and was talked about in session 218 ("Custom Transitions Using View Controllers") of the WWDC 2013. You should check those out.